# We can't initialize Express Checkout. in Magento2.1.9

Tags: magento2, paypal

There are already many thread for the problem, But As I check the code why I am receiving this error is -  when user returning from paypal-express to site then in `Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress.php` its not found `quote` object in function `_initCheckout()`.

In this file its trying to fetch quote object from checkout session "$this->_quote = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();" but its not, thats why giving "We can't initialize Express Checkout" error.

All process working fine on my local system but not on the server. In current condition - Css/Js not merged, all cache flushed multiple times, also tried by changing session storage location to 'db' but didn't found solution till yet.

Please reply.

Comment: did you found any solution?